# ggplot2 boxplot legend order does not match the levels of the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the order of a boxplot legend. Despite having already changed the levels of the data to my desired order, the legend still displays alphabetically. I am thinking this has something to do with the fact that I have reordered "Drugs" (which shows up on the graph correctly) and am also trying to reorder "Drug.class" (the colours; which does not show up in the correct order.

This is the plot that I have currently:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIgCo.png)

My code is below. Any help appreciated!

```
  mutate(Drug = fct_relevel(Drug,
                            'DMSO',
                            'AURKBi',
                            'Taxol',
                            'IR',
                            'Actinomycin D',
                            'Cisplatin',
                            'MMC',
                            'CPT',
                            'MMS',
                            'HU',
                            'SRSF1 KD',
                            'Triptolide',
                            'DRB'))



drug_quant_df = drug_quant_df %>% 
  mutate(Drug.class = fct_relevel(Drug.class,
                            'Control',
                            'Aneugen',
                            'Clastogen',
                            'Transcription'))

ggplot(drug_quant_df) +
  aes(x=Drug, y=mn_over_cells, colour=Drug.class) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.2,
              position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2)) +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(option="C", end=0.8) +
  theme_classic(12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: In the body of you post, please include the name of any packages you are using. `mutate` and `%>%` are available in base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the order of your legend labels by passing the argument `breaks` in `scale_color_viridis_d` function.

Here an example:

Without passing `breaks` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)
txsamp <- subset(txhousing, city %in%
                   c("Houston", "Fort Worth", "San Antonio", "Dallas", "Austin"))
ggplot(data = txsamp, aes(x = sales, y = median)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = city))+ 
  scale_colour_viridis_d()
```

[image]

And now by passing the right order in the `breaks` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)
txsamp <- subset(txhousing, city %in%
                   c("Houston", "Fort Worth", "San Antonio", "Dallas", "Austin"))
ggplot(data = txsamp, aes(x = sales, y = median)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = city))+ 
  scale_colour_viridis_d(breaks = c("Dallas","San Antonio","Houston","Austin","Fort Worth"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `fct_relevel` doesn't do what you think it does. If I do

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = c("6", "4", "8"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point()
```

I get the order I set in the `factor` function.

[image]